# Using holoviews renderer with datashader in a script

Tags: python, holoviews, datashader

I’m trying to use HoloViews + Datashaeder as part of a python script instead of exclusively in notebooks.

I can create the plot and view it in a notebook but when I follow the example from the FAQ for rendering without the notebook, I receive errors for bokeh:

```
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np
from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade, dynspread
hv.extension('bokeh')

np.random.seed(1)
positions = np.random.multivariate_normal((0,0),[[0.1,0.1], [0.1,1.0]], (1000000,))
points = hv.Points(positions,label="Points")
plot = datashade(points) + dynspread(datashade(points))

renderer = hv.renderer('matplotlib').instance(fig='html')
renderer.save(plot,'testing')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "holoviews_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    renderer.save(plt_out, 'exampleFAQ2') 
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/holoviews/plotting/renderer.py", line 465, in save
    plot = self_or_cls.get_plot(obj)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/renderer.py", line 112, in get_plot
    plot = super(BokehRenderer, self_or_cls).get_plot(obj, renderer)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/holoviews/plotting/renderer.py", line 177, in get_plot
    **plot_opts)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/raster.py", line 20, in __init__
    super(RasterPlot, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/element.py", line 180, in __init__
    self.callbacks = self._construct_callbacks()
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/element.py", line 216, in _construct_callbacks
    cbs.append(cb(self, cb_streams, source))
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/callbacks.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.comm = self._comm_type(plot, on_msg=self.on_msg)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/holoviews/plotting/comms.py", line 210, in __init__
    self.manager = get_ipython().kernel.comm_manager
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kernel'
```

and when I try to make the same plot with matplotlib:

```
hv.extension('matplotlib')
renderer = hv.renderer('matplotlib').instance(fig='png')
renderer.save(plot,'testing')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "holoviews_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    renderer.save(plt_out, 'exampleFAQ2') #, style=dict(Image=
    {'cmap':'jet'}))
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/holoviews/plotting/renderer.py", line 465, in save
    plot = self_or_cls.get_plot(obj)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/holoviews/plotting/renderer.py", line 178, in get_plot
    plot.update(0)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/holoviews/plotting/mpl/plot.py", line 244, in update
    return self.initialize_plot()
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/holoviews/plotting/mpl/plot.py", line 43, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/holoviews/plotting/mpl/plot.py", line 1090, in 
    initialize_plot
    hspace=self.hspace*self.fig_scale)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/holoviews/plotting/mpl/util.py", line 113, in fix_aspect
    bbox = ax.get_tightbbox(fig.canvas.renderer)
AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasMac' object has no attribute 'renderer'
```

The rendering example code works for basic holoviews Elements but fails once I add the multiple datashader methods. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This is likely a bug and I've filed an issue with HoloViews [here](https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/issues/1994). What is happening here is that `datashade` attaches so called streams to the plot which update the plot whenever the axis ranges change. You can manually disable this behavior by setting `datashade.dynamic=False` on datashade or pass it directly to the call.

Here's a version of your example that works (note also that I've changed the `fig` format to `'svg'` since matplotlib does not render natively to `'html'` as you had originally declared:

```
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np
from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade, dynspread
hv.extension('bokeh')

#### Disable dynamic updating of plot
datashade.dynamic = False

np.random.seed(1)
positions = np.random.multivariate_normal((0,0),[[0.1,0.1], [0.1,1.0]], (1000000,))
points = hv.Points(positions,label="Points")
plot = datashade(points, dynamic=False) + dynspread(datashade(points))

renderer = hv.renderer('matplotlib').instance(fig='svg')
renderer.save(plot,'testing')
```

Comment: If I add the dynamic keyword as well as specifying x_range and y_range for the datashade function, the plot will save using bokeh + html.

However, this code with matplotlib gives me the same FigureCanvasMac error as above. Maybe it's my matplotlib version? I'm currently using matplotlib 2.0.0, holoviews 1.8.3, and datashader 0.4.0